# How to make use of app(unstable structure) folder in ionic 2 inside the stable version

Tags: angular, upgrade, ionic2, ng-upgrade

I have update my ionic 2 version to stable.

After giving **ionic start myProject blank --v2** i am getting the folder structure like ionic 1. take a look at the folder [structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dank8.png) i got.

here is my **ionic info** command result

```
Cordova CLI: 6.3.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.0
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.0-beta.1
OS: Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS 
Node Version: v4.2.6
```

here is my **package.json** file

```
{
  "name": "ionic-hello-world",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "watch": "ionic-app-scripts watch",
    "serve:before": "watch",
    "emulate:before": "build",
    "deploy:before": "build",
    "build:before": "build",
    "run:before": "build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ionic-angular": "^2.0.0-rc.0",
    "ionicons": "^3.0.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "^1.0.3",
    "ionic-native": "^2.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^0.0.23",
    "typescript": "^2.0.3"
  },
  "description": "myProject: An Ionic project",
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": []
}
```

**Questions:**

> After updating my ionic 2 and try to create a project when i see the structure i am not able to see my **app** folder. why ???
>
> when i give **ionic serve --lab** command i believe i am getting **index.html** file loaded. if so how my indicate my unstable app folder to the existing(updated stable version) project
>
> can any one reefer me to understand the structure. i believe it is similar to the ionic 1. but i have completed my project into ionic 2(unstable). but now the structure is different. so how can i make use of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After following the https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#steps-to-upgrade-to-rc0

i am able to solve my issue

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct behaviour, the directory structure has changed in RC 0.
The `src` folder will contain all the source files and assets and the `www` file folderbe fully generated.